# How to know if inapp subscriptionperiod finish or user has cancel it?

Tags: java, android

Simple as that, I made a program with subscription, when the user subscribe, a boolean value turns to true.
when i test my software, if i cancel the subscription or it is automatically finished, the boolean value still return true.

I need to put in my code a check to see if the subscription is still available or not

As I am new to android studio, I have looked for that problem for 2 weeks so far but didn't find a solution for it.
All the solutions and posts are talking a bout the old in-App library (AIDL) with this magic line

Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);

but it seems that doesn't work in the new Google Play Billing library.

here is my Billing Activity:

;

public class BillingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PurchasesUpdatedListener {

```
private static final String TAG = "BillingActivity";

private Button button;
protected SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
private boolean checkActivation;
private BillingClient mBillingClient;
private List<String> skuList;
private SkuDetailsParams.Builder skuParams;
private BillingFlowParams flowParams;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_billing);


    // Shred Preferences & Active user Initialize
    checkActivation = false;
    mSharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.aterosolutions.customerspremiums", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (mSharedPreferences.getInt("activeUser", 0) == 1) { // 0 ==> InActiveUser   1 ==> ActiveUser
        //mSharedPreferences.edit().putInt("activeUser", 1).apply();
        checkActivation = true;
    } else {
        //mSharedPreferences.edit().putInt("activeUser", 0).apply();
        checkActivation = false;
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, checkActivation + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    // SKU List
    skuList = new ArrayList<>();
    skuList.add("premiums_subscribe");
    skuParams = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
    skuParams.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);

    // Establish connection to billing client
    mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this).build();
    mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished: start" + billingResult.getResponseCode());
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished: second congrat");
            } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished: you own it");
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished: not your product");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            Toast.makeText(BillingActivity.this, "Connection Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i(TAG, "onBillingServiceDisconnected: Connection Error");

        }
    });


    queryPurchases();
    //checkPurchsedItem();

    // Button Handle
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(skuParams.build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                    flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList.get(0)).build();
                    BillingResult response = mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(BillingActivity.this, flowParams);
                    Log.i(TAG, "onSkuDetailsResponse: " + billingResult.getResponseCode());
                    Log.i(TAG, "onSkuDetailsResponse: response OK");
                    Log.i(TAG, "onSkuDetailsResponse: my test" + response);
                    Log.i(TAG, "onSkuDetailsResponse: queryPurshase01 " + mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS));

                    /* (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList != null) {
                        flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList.get(0)).build();
                        mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(BillingActivity.this, flowParams);
                        Log.i(TAG, "onSkuDetailsResponse: response OK");

                    }else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED && skuDetailsList != null){
                        Log.i(TAG, "onSkuDetailsResponse: response already Owned");
                    }else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onSkuDetailsResponse: response something else");
                    }*/
                }
            });
        }
    });

}


@Override
public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onPurchasesUpdated: start /// purchses"+ billingResult.getResponseCode() );

    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK /*&& purchases != null*/) {
        mSharedPreferences.edit().putInt("activeUser", 1).apply();
        MainScreenActivity.activeUser = true;
        for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
            handleNewPurchase(purchase);
        }
    } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED /*&& purchases != null*/) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPurchasesUpdated: You Already Own It");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Already Owned", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mSharedPreferences.edit().putInt("activeUser", 1).apply();
        MainScreenActivity.activeUser = true;

    } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED /*&& purchases != null*/) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPurchasesUpdated: User Canceled");
        Toast.makeText(this, "User Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPurchasesUpdated: other error " + billingResult.getResponseCode());

    }


}

private void handleNewPurchase(Purchase purchase) {

    Log.i(TAG, "handleNewPurchase: queryPurshase00 " + mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS).getBillingResult());

    for (int i = 0; i < skuList.size(); i++) {
        if (purchase.getSku() == skuList.get(i)) {
            mSharedPreferences.edit().putInt("activeUser", 1).apply();
            MainScreenActivity.activeUser = true;
            Toast.makeText(this, "congrat dear", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i(TAG, "handleNewPurchase: product purchsed ");

            // Acknowledge the purchase if it hasn't already been acknowledged.
            if (!purchase.isAcknowledged()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "handlePurchase: ok02");
                AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                        .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                        .build();

                AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener = new AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse(BillingResult billingResult) {


                    }

                };
                Log.i(TAG, "handleNewPurchase: aknowledge done");
                mBillingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener);
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "handleNewPurchase: no need to aknowledge");
            }
        }
    }
}

private void queryPurchases() {
    Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
    if (purchasesResult != null) {
        List<Purchase> purchaseList = purchasesResult.getPurchasesList();
        if (purchaseList == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (!purchaseList.isEmpty()){
            for (Purchase purchase : purchaseList){
                if (purchase.getSku().equals(skuList.get(0))){
                    //mSharedPreferences.edit().putInt("activeUser", 1).apply();
                    //MainScreenActivity.activeUser = true;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mBillingClient.endConnection();

}

private void checkPurchsedItem(){
    mBillingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS, new PurchaseHistoryResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPurchaseHistoryResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<PurchaseHistoryRecord> purchaseHistoryRecordList) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPurchaseHistoryResponse: " + billingResult.getResponseCode());
        }
    });

    Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
    Log.i(TAG, "checkPurchsedItem: " + purchasesResult.getBillingResult());
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "checkPurchsedItem: " + purchasesResult.getPurchasesList().size());
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "checkPurchsedItem: " + purchasesResult.getResponseCode());
    Log.i(TAG, "checkPurchsedItem: " + purchasesResult.getBillingResult());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After lots of headache (like always with Google APIs and services) I figured out how one can access Google Play Developer API information (like billing) by using existing APIs.

1.) Create in Developer API Console a service account (JSON) key:

[image]

2.) Download this service-account-private-key.json file (don't mistake it with the OAuth2.0 client secret file!).

3.) In Google Play Developer Console go to Settings -> Users & Permissions -> Invite New User and set as user e-mail of the new user the client_email from the downloaded file. Assign the access rights you want to give to this users via the checkboxes inside this view (for example 'View financial data').

4.) Add the proper dependency to your project (version ...-1.23.0 does not work for me):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-androidpublisher</artifactId>
    <version>v2-rev50-1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
```

5.) Load the service-account-private-key.json file into your application. In my case it's a webserver:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class WebserverConfiguration
{
    private String serviceAccountPrivateKeyFilePath;

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    public static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    public static JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY;

    private GoogleCredential credential;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        assignServiceAccountFileProperty();
        initGoogleCredentials();
    }

    public String getServiceAccountPrivateKeyFilePath()
    {
        return serviceAccountPrivateKeyFilePath;
    }

    public GoogleCredential getCredential()
    {
        return credential;
    }

    private void initGoogleCredentials()
    {
        try
        {
            newTrustedTransport();
            newJsonFactory();

            String serviceAccountContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(getServiceAccountPrivateKeyFilePath())));
            InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(serviceAccountContent.getBytes());

            credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(inputStream).createScoped(Collections.singleton(AndroidPublisherScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER));

        }
        catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e)
        {
            throw new InitializationException(e);
        }
    }

    private void newJsonFactory()
    {
        JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    private void assignServiceAccountFileProperty()
    {
        serviceAccountPrivateKeyFilePath = System.getProperty("service.account.file.path");
        if (serviceAccountPrivateKeyFilePath == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("service.account.file.path UNKNOWN - configure it as VM startup parameter in Wildfly");
        }
    }

    private static void newTrustedTransport() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
    {
        if (HTTP_TRANSPORT == null)
        {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        }
    }
}
6.) Now I am able the fetch Google Play Developer API information, e.g. reviews:

private void invokeGoogleApi() throws IOException
{       
    AndroidPublisher publisher = new AndroidPublisher.Builder(WebserverConfiguration.HTTP_TRANSPORT, WebserverConfiguration.JSON_FACTORY, configuration.getCredential()).setApplicationName("The name of my app on Google Play").build();
    AndroidPublisher.Reviews reviews = publisher.reviews();
    ReviewsListResponse reviewsListResponse = reviews.list("the.packagename.of.my.app").execute();
    logger.info("review list response = " + reviewsListResponse.toPrettyString());
}
This worked.

I cannot test it yet, but I'm sure that fetching the billing information works as well:

private SubscriptionPurchase getPurchase() throws IOException
{
    AndroidPublisher publisher = new AndroidPublisher.Builder(WebserverConfiguration.HTTP_TRANSPORT, WebserverConfiguration.JSON_FACTORY, configuration.getCredential()).setApplicationName("The name of my app on Google Play").build();
    AndroidPublisher.Purchases purchases = publisher.purchases();

    SubscriptionPurchase purchase = purchases.subscriptions().get("the.packagename.of.my.app", "subscriptionId", "billing token sent by the app").execute();

    //do something or return
    return purchase;
}
```

Comment: I manged to do the fisrt4 step .. the fifth one shall i create a new class.. and call the method from my billing class?